# Find if value is max for previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
num val
0   77
1   78
2   78
3   79
4   80
5   81
6   79
7   83
8   85
9   86
10  87
11  88
12  89
13  90
14  91
15  90
16  92
```

I want to create new bool column with values True or False. This depends on if current value is maximum for previous 4 rows (larger than values in 4 previous rows).
Expected output:

```
num val is_max
0   77  NaN
1   78  NaN
2   78  NaN
3   79  NaN
4   80  True
5   81  True
6   79  False
7   83  True
8   85  True
9   86  True
10  87  True
11  88  True
12  89  True
13  90  True
14  91  True
15  90  False
16  92  True
```

Comment: Where's your code? It's hard to help you fix your code without the code.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson, oh dear friend, I don't have solution to do it. I can do it in ugly way with iterations (everybody can code it, its simple), but I expect elegant way with pandas.

Comment: pandas.DataFrame.rolling is your friend.

Comment: @IgorK, I've edit my answer. Take a look at it when you get a change. Mixing data types in Pandas will return an `object` dtype, or it'll automatically convert data to `float`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this can be solved by evaluating the condition with the `.rolling()` function for the window you are calculating over. All in all the code would be as follows:

```
df['is_max'] = df['val'].rolling(4).max() > df['val']
```

Since your expected output seems to be the negation of the one I am achieving while keeping the first 3 rows as np.nan, we need to first skip the rows and then proceed to do the comparison:

```
df['is_max'] = np.where(df['val'].rolling(4).max().isna(),np.nan,(df['val'].rolling(4).max() > df['val']))
```

Given there are NaN's in the column with the True or False statement, pandas will force this True / False boolean to be converted into floats of 1 and 0 (which represents the same). Regardless of the approach you take, as soon as you add `NaN`s to the column, the True and False values will be forced into 1 and 0 respectively

Comment: Agreed, it is better, thanks for the comment

Comment: I would recommend checking the output. I think it's not working as expected.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. Symbol '~' do the job. This saves me many hours of computation through iteration. But there is one point. It is easily solved by cutting off the first rows. But still. The first 4 values are worthless. They now become True. How to make them NaN?

Comment: @CeliusStingher 0,1,2,3 give worthless results. So these rows should be NaN. Starting from row 4 results are good.

Comment: Please check the comment together with the note of the True / False

Comment: @CeliusStingher Dear friend, thank you for helping! The last thing I'm asking is where to use the "~" symbol? The result requires inversion as in the previous case. Now True and False are reversed. I tried to put ~ before np.where, but it returns error

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, the `~` symbol can be used for a boolean series, in which case we would need to define a series from the array that is returned from `np.where`. You would need something like `~(pd.Series(np.where(...)))`. Or, if you wish to force the `True/False`, you can turn them as strings with `map({0:'True',1:'False'})` but this would be counter-intuitive and I would not recommend it.

Comment: @CeliusStingher my database is very big so speed matters to me. df ['val']. Rolling (4) .max ()> df ['val'] is faster than the second with np.where, so I took first solution and just cut first worthless rows. Thank you, dear friend, for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use groupby every 4 rows and find the expanding max.

```
df.val.eq(df.groupby(df.index//4).val.transform(lambda x: x.expanding().max()))
```

Comment: ummmm  expanding ?, expanding will take pervious n (row number) not pervious 4 . you can try change the first 77 to 999

Comment: *This depends on if current value is maximum for previous 4 rows (larger than values in 4 previous rows)* and the logic here is take the pervious 4 not pervious all row

Comment: @BENY in what instances would it fail so that w work around it?

Comment: as I told u change the 77 to 999 you will see all False

Comment: @BENY thanks for the spotting. Edited to group by before equating

Answer (score 2):

Since `rolling` also takes the current row, you may need to use `shift` or increase the window by one. Take a look at the respective codes below:

```py
df['is_max'] = df.val[n:] > df.val.shift(1).rolling(n).max().dropna()
```

or

```py
df['is_max'] = df.val.iloc[n:].eq(df.val.rolling(n+1).max().dropna())
```

where `n` stands by the last `n` rows.

---

Output:

```
    num  val is_max
0     0   77    NaN
1     1   78    NaN
2     2   78    NaN
3     3   79    NaN
4     4   80   True
5     5   81   True
6     6   79  False
7     7   83   True
8     8   85   True
9     9   86   True
10   10   87   True
11   11   88   True
12   12   89   True
13   13   90   True
14   14   91   True
15   15   90  False
16   16   92   True
```

---

Note that, the output dtype for "is_max" column is `object` because it has mixed data types (`NaN` and `bool`), and pandas doesn't accept it. Pandas either convert the column dtype to `object` or `float`. However, it also provides a [nullable bollean data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/boolean.html) so that you can force "is_max" column to `boolean` with: `df.is_max.astype('boolean')`.